# How can I get all the values individually in an xml file using Linq to xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml, excel, linq-to-xml

If for example I have a nested xml like this

```
<Root>
  <NodeA>
    <NodeA1>
      <NodeA11>
        <SameNameNode>
          <SameNameNodeChild1>Value 1</SameNameNodeChild1>
          <SameNameNodeChild2>Value 2</SameNameNodeChild2>
        </SameNameNode>
      </NodeA11>
    </NodeA1>
  </NodeA>
  <NodeB>
    <SameNameNode>
      <SameNameNodeChild1>Value 3</SameNameNodeChild1>
      <SameNameNodeChild2>Value 4</SameNameNodeChild2>
    </SameNameNode>
  </NodeB>
  <NodeC>
    <NodeC1>
      <SameNameNode>
        <SameNameNodeChild1>Value 5</SameNameNodeChild1>
        <SameNameNodeChild2>Value 6</SameNameNodeChild2>
      </SameNameNode>
    </NodeC1>
  </NodeC>
```

How can I retrieve all the the values
values 1 all the way to value 6 and store them in an excel sheet?

Currently the code I am having is

```
  foreach (XElement DirectChild in xml.Descendants())
            {
                foreach (XElement child in DirectChild.Descendants())
                {

                    foreach (XElement GrandChild in DirectChild.Elements())
                    {

                    dataList.Add(GrandChild.Value);

                    }

            }
```

and place the data into an excel sheet.

Although the data format I am getting is this

in 1 cell 
{value 1 value 2}

in 2nd cell {value 1}

in 3rd cell {value 2}

in cell 4 {value 3 value 4}

cell 5 {value 3}

cell 6 {value 4}

Is there any way to dynamically  get each value individually without getting the value in groups, I have about 100 xml files to convert and I don't think I can do it tag specifically

Any ideas?

Comment: intended outcome is cell 1: value 1; cell 2: value 2; cell 3: value 3; and so on and so forth

Comment: Can you be more specific why cell you want the data?  The sample input doesn't always have the same number of elements.  Also do you need the element names.  I looks like you are attempting to group the data from the 100 files, but not sure what the requirements for the groupings.

Comment: sorry the input i placed was wrong for every element grp the data will be inside 1 cell in this case value 1 and 2 will be grped in a cell 4 times before separating them into 1  cell each. i do not know the requirements of the groupings the only task is that each value is in its own cell

Comment: You have to plan this task.  Start looking at more than one file to determine how to put the data into the worksheet so the data doesn't overlap.  When in college the teacher gave an assignment to read student data from a file.  The first file had no errors. .Second file had error.   By the time I got done I had over 500 punch cards to get the program to run on a batch system where it took 4 hours to get print out.  And had over 1000 punch cards in the circular basket.  Now it takes only minutes and no punch cards.  But you do not want to making changes to the program.  Do the design first.

Answer (score 0):

edit: example of filtering on elements that don't have sub elements

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(@"<Root>
  <NodeA>value</NodeA>
  <NodeB>value</NodeB>
  <NodeC>
    <NodeD>value</NodeD>
  </NodeC>
  </Root>
  ");

foreach(var el in root.Descendants())
{
    if(!el.HasElements)
        Console.WriteLine(el.ToString());
}
```

Comment: as i stated is there anyway to do things without writing down the tag names as the hundred xml files may have different tag names which would make it more difficult to do things tag specific. thank you for your quick reply

Comment: Sorry I didn't read properly. If you know elements that have text values will not nest other elements, then you can filter on the elements using this as a test. See edited answer for an example